# nodejs express length of list in a model as a response

Tags: node.js, api, express, mongoose, models

How can I calculate the length of a list in one of the parameters of a model, and add that length to another parameter of that same model so that it can be send back as part of the response by the api?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ArrayOfUser = require('../models/arrayofuser')

var usersSchema = new Schema({
    items: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ArrayOfUser'},
    total: items.length

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

These are called [virtual properties](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html), functionality directly provided by mongoose:

### Code

The way to achieve it in your case would be:

```
const usersSchema = new Schema({
    items: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ArrayOfUser'},
},{
    toObject: {virtuals: true}, toJSON: {virtuals: true}
})

usersSchema.virtual('total')
    .get(function() {return this.items.length})
```

---

### Followup to Comments:

Here is the fixed Node route method for the feedback below! Good luck :)

```js
//GET array of users data via api
app.get('/api/v1/users', (req, res) => {
  const pagesToSkip = ~~req.query.pagesToSkip
  const pageSize = ~~req.query.pageSize
  const searchText = req.query.pagesToSkip
  // var searchText = {}
  Users.find().populate('items').exec((err, users) => {
    if (err) {return res.send(err)}
    res.send(users) // I'd recommend `res.json({users})`, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  })
})

// NOTE: The `~~x` is a code-golfy way of Saying Math.floor(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link; I read read into.  There was no way I would have figured that out searching online.  Just one last thing, I'm now getting the following issue.  I'm currently searching for an answer, but any ideas why it sees "length" as undefined?................ Connected to mongodb
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wilbe\Documents\SummitWorks\2-Project-Inventory-webapp\server\inventory_project-ten\inventory_project-ten\backend\models\users.js:19:40)

Comment: It's really hard for me to debug that for you, since I don't have access to the data, and I don't know what the existing Documents in your collection look like. But I have a feeling you're missing `.populate()`. here's the link: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html

Comment: :D wow all that info just blew my mind off. I'm going to take a day to digest this...Thanks for your help; I'll start reading into this...Oh, here's my api call....//GET array of users data via api
app.get('/api/v1/users', (req,res) => {
    var pagesToSkip = parseInt(req.query.pagesToSkip)
    var pageSize = parseInt(req.query.pageSize)
    var searchText = req.query.pagesToSkip
    // var searchText = {}

    Users.find((err, users) => {
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.send(users);
        }
    });
});

Comment: Hey @WilberH. addressed your concerns in my answer, if this helped please make sure to upvote and mark the answer as accepted.